# Firefox SDK doing a request more than once

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I am doing a server request with my firefox sdk, which replies a XML file.

I am parsing the XML file for two special values and put them into a global array (in my `onComplete` function).

My Problem is that the array does not save the values in element `0` and `1` and I don't know why!

My second Problem is that I want to call a request in my addon for the current tab `url` (that means more than one time). I know the request module says "Each Request object is designed to be used once" but is it possible to call it more than once?

I always get this error :

> Error: This request object has been used already. You must create a new one to make a new request.

```
var Request = require("request").Request;
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);
var setURL = "example.org";
var exampleArray = new Array();

function parseResponse(response) {  
    var xml = parser.parseFromString(response.text, "application/xml");  
    exampleArray[0] = xml.getElementsByTagName("example")[0].getAttribute("example"); // integer value
    exampleArray[1] = xml.getElementsByTagName("example2")[0].getAttribute("example2"); //integer value
 }

var exampleRequest = Request({
      url: "http://www.example.com",
      onComplete: parseResponse, 
})
exampleRequest.get();

console.log("exampleArray" + exampleArray.length); //always 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your request call in a function that's reusable. `Request` is a constructor, so you can instantiate several requests. But each request can only request one URL.

```
function request (url) {
  Request({
    url: url
    onComplete: parseResponse, 
  }).get();
}
```

For the XML issue, just console log the individual nodes, probably not what you expect somewhere.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution, didnt thought that it would be so easy to use a request more often :)
When i log my example array inside of the parseResponse function it works fine but its not a global save, i dont get it :(

Comment: Well on each `parseResponse`, you'll be overriding the first 2 values of the array on every call. Maybe you mean to use push instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: I guess my problem was that i didn't thought about the asynchrony of javascript here. A friend told me that i have to work with callbacks here, so i will give it a try!